# Confused about asynchronous image loading

Tags: android

I am  tring to retrieve  image from raw folder using AsyncTask  class. I  am working on this sample for hours . .I dont get any exceptions but nothing will display on the screen .Probably missing out lots of things.Could you please  check for my code.What am i doing wrong again

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView img;
    asynclass Myclass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img=new ImageView(this);
    /***
     *  Field[] filelds=R.raw.class.getFields();
        String [] names=new String[filelds.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < filelds.length; i++) {
       names[i]=filelds[i].getName()+".jpg";

        }
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * */

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, names[0], 0).show();
        String s="android.resource://"+getApplication().getPackageName()+"/raw/d.jpg/";

        this.setContentView(img, 
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Myclass=(asynclass) new asynclass().execute(s);


    }

    public class asynclass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            Bitmap bmp=null;

            bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0]);

            return bmp;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result!=null){
                img.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }



    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `setContentView` method two times?

Comment: Is `bmp` null after `decodeFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is the *fastest way* to fix your specific problem (as in, fewest changes to get a working snippet), but I'll follow up with what should be here.

For starters, when I ran your code exactly as you have it, I found that the result you get in your `AsyncTask` was returning `null`.  This is because the absolute file path you're giving is not what `BitmapFactory` is looking for.

As a quick fix, make the following changes:

```
//Remove this line
//String s="android.resource://"+getApplication().getPackageName()+"/raw/d.jpg/";

this.setContentView(img, 
       new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//Remove the "s" from your execute
Myclass=(asynclass) new asynclass().execute();
```

And in your `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

   Bitmap bmp=null;

   //Change this line to use decodeResource instead of decodeFile
   bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.raw.d);

   return bmp;
}
```

This should make your code *work*, but it will not be conveniently reproducible.

Now as for how you *should* be doing it, you call `setContentView()` twice, which is redundant, and you create an `ImageView` and replace the layout resource that you set with a different one.

You will need to look into the xml file `activity_main.xml` to do this, but the following is just an example of what it could look like:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now with the above layout file, you can change the start of your `onCreate()` method to read as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    Myclass=(asynclass) new asynclass().execute();
}
```

Getting used to using the resource files will make loading multiple images and views much easier later on.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Some things I see:

1) You can access resources from the `raw` folder using `R.raw.fileName`.

2) You shouldn't call `setContentView()` more than once

3) No need to cast your `AsyncTask`.

I would suggest you spend some time going over some tutorials, so you can get a solid Android foundation.

Comment: As @Emmanuel said you have a lot of fundamental mistakes, try to spend  some time for getting started with Android.

Answer (score 0):

This code with @Emmanuel's comments should work. Spend your time and compare your and my code. Read an tutorials. And see some sources in OpenSource libs.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView mImage;
    private ImageLoader loader;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // 2) You shouldn't call setContentView() more than once
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImage = new ImageView(this);

        // 3) No need to cast your AsyncTask.
        new ImageLoader().execute(R.raw.d);
    }

    public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // 1) You can access resources from the raw folder using R.raw.fileName
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if(result != null){
                mImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }
}
```